# What was Yukteshwar Giri's opinion on meat-eating?

Tags: food, non-vegetarian

What was Yukteshwar Giri's view on meat-eating? Was He a vegetarian?

Comment: ..........who ?

Comment: @ram .....What?

Comment: He asked who. The person you named

Comment: @ram Yukteshwa was an Advaita Swami who claimed to have met Mahavtar Babaji.

Comment: @ram Yukteshwar Giri was a disciple of Lahiri Mahasaya of the line of Kriya Yogis, and the Guru of Sri Paramahansa Yogananda. Lahiri Mahasaya's Guru apparently is Mahavatar Babaji.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yukteshwar believed in strict vegetarianism.** Under Chapter 3 Sutras 9-11 of his book ["The Holy Science"](http://www.starcenter.com/holy-science.pdf), Yukteshwar argues that the human body is not designed to eat meat.  He cites many pieces of evidence for this, for instance the shape of human teeth:

> By observation of the teeth we find that in carnivourous animals the incisors are little developed, but the canines are of striking length, smooth and pointed, to seize the prey. The molars also are pointed; these points, however, do not meet, but fit closely side by side to separate the muscular fibers. In the herbivorous animals the incisors are strikingly developed, the canines are stunted (though occasionally developed into weapons, as in elephants), the molars are broad-topped and furnished with enamel on the sides only. In the frugivorous all the teeth are of nearly the same height; the canines are little projected, conical, and blunt (obviously not inteded for seizing prey but for exertion of strenth), The molars are broad-topped and furnished at the top with enamel folds to prevent waste caused by their side motion, but not pointed for chewing flesh. In Omnivorous animals such as bears, on the other hand, the incisors resemble those of the herbivorous, the canines are like those of the carnivorous, and the molars are both pointed and broad-topped to serve a twofold purpose. Now if we observe the formation of the teeth in man we find that they do not resemble those of the carnivores, neither do they resemble the teeth of the herbivorous or the omnivorous. They do resemble, eactly, those of the frugivorous animals. The reasonable inference, therefore, is that man is a frugivorous or fruit-eating animal.

He cites other evidence as well, like the shape of the human digestive canal, humans' instinctual revulsion at killing animals, etc., and then he reaches this conclusion:

> Hence from these observations the only conclusion that can reasonably be drawn is that various grains, fruits, roots, and – for beverage – milk, and pure water openly exposed to air and sun are decidedly the best natural food for man. These, being congenial to the system when taken according to the power of the digestive organs, well chewed and mixed with saliva, are always easily assimilated. Other foods are unnatural to man and being uncongenial to the system are necessarily foreign to it; when they enter the stomach, they are not properly assimilated. Mixed with the blood, they accumulate in the excretory and other organs not properly adapted to them. When they cannot find their way out, they subside in tissue crevices by the law of gravitation; and being fermented, produce diseases, mental and physical, and ultimately lead to premature death.

Comment: But my question is, although I won't dare to refute Sri Yukteshwar Giri, I am just a little uneasy. Does modern medical science agree to the facts he mentioned? Its not that I prefer science over Yoga. Its somewhat the reverse. But I would definitely love to see a parity between the two views.

Comment: @ArkaprabhaMajumdar actually this does not agree with biological findings, but that is not a subject of this forum. Others have said it is ok to consume some meat. Strict vegetarianism is best for yogis who have abandoned worldly duties. Vivekananda said don't worry about giving up meat, it will give you up when the time is right.

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda I am actually not against any yogi or any spiritual science. And since I have read about what you said about Vivekananda (my family is initiated from RKM Belur Matt) I actually saw this for the first time and was a bit uneasy. I know that this discipline requires vegetarianism, but I still know of a few Yogis connected to my family who ate meat. However I've heard that those incidents only occurred in front of devotees who offered him meat, I don't know what he consumed when he was in solitude. He even cooked prawns for a beloved devotee.

Comment: @ArkaprabhaMajumdar as I said, when it is time, it will give you up. After realization, it does not matter what you consume. For people that have to do worldly work everyday, need to lead a rajasic life, a little meat is ok. For a sadhu, he should eat what is offered to him. A sadhu accepts what is offered to him as coming from God, that is why they do not turn it down. Remember Buddha died because he ate pork that was offered to him. Read Vivekanada's Complete Works. If being a strict vegetarian was the way to God, cows and sheep would be realized beings. See Wikipedia page on vitamin B12.

Comment: Yes, I've read some part of Complete Works, mostly on the diet portion. I agree with that. After realization, you develop total detachment, so eating meat won't affect you because you're not getting attached like mundane people. Same for every other thing.

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda how does science not agree with this.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion swamiji was not advocating vegetarianism with the help of some personal arguments in favour of it. He had revealed a solid scientific concept on the basis of anatomical and physiological observation of the human race with regard to the most appropriate energy source for humans in general. He had not expected all humans to follow suit. Academicians may try to disprove him rather than expressing their likes and dislikes!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).